# I need to transform the jsonline to df

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonlines

Below is the example of my jsonline data

```
{"allocation":{"duration":1,"rewards":[{"expiryDate":"2021-01-01 23:59:59","rewardSubType":"Boxes"}]},"MODULE":"a","APPLICATION":"g","GUID2":"gh-gh-gh","METHOD":"Expensive","timestamp":"2021-01-01 07:00:00.497"}
{"allocation":{"duration":2,"rewards":[{"expiryDate":"2021-01-02 23:59:59","rewardSubType":"Keys"}]},"MODULE":"a","APPLICATION":"b","GUID":"gh-gh-gh","METHOD":"Free","timestamp":"2021-01-02 07:00:00.497"}
```

I have run the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

with open('C:\\Vodacom\\KPI Dashboard\\ussd_vservices_audit.jsonl') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

df_inter = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df_inter.columns = ['json_element']
df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads)
df_final = pd.json_normalize(df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads))
df_final
```

That results in

[image: result]

However, I need to further split up the newly created allocation.rewards (old "rewards") column into  separate columns too. It now has square brackets and single quotes too so I have no idea how to do this.

Please assist
Thanks!

Amazing answer thank you - exactly what I needed! But now I have found when running against my full dataset, I have some rows of data that don't have a rewards section/column as below:

```
{"offer":null,"MODULE":"purchase","APPLICATION":"new","GUID":"cf-83-11-001","METHOD":"Upsize","timestamp":"2021-02-01 06:00:01.158"}
```

This causes me to then have the error
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: You don't need to import json_normalize as you have already imported it as part of the pandas package as pd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue your script with below code and get the desired results:

```py
for index, row in df_final.iterrows():
  value = row["allocation.rewards"]
  if value == value and len(value) == 1:
    for key, keyValue in value[0].items():
      df_final.loc[index, key] = keyValue
df_final.drop(columns=["allocation.rewards"], inplace=True)
df_final
```

##### Output

|  | MODULE | APPLICATION | GUID2 | METHOD | timestamp | allocation.duration | GUID | offer | expiryDate | rewardSubType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | g | gh-gh-gh | Expensive | 2021-01-01 07:00:00.497 | 1 | nan | nan | 2021-01-01 23:59:59 | Boxes |
| 1 | a | b | nan | Free | 2021-01-02 07:00:00.497 | 2 | gh-gh-gh | nan | 2021-01-02 23:59:59 | Keys |
| 2 | purchase | new | nan | Upsize | 2021-02-01 06:00:01.158 | nan | cf-83-11-001 | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. But then I ran it against my full dataset where I have rows that don't include the allocation.rewards in the jsonlines row. I have included an example in my original comment. This now throws a new error:
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
How do I handle that?

Comment: @ByronFox Thanks for sharing your error. I have edited my answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your `rewards` value only contains one element in list, you can explode `allocation.rewards` column in `df_final`

```py
df_final['allocation.rewards'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row[0]))

            expiryDate rewardSubType
0  2021-01-01 23:59:59         Boxes
1  2021-01-02 23:59:59          Keys
```

Then concat it to df_final and drop the `allocation.rewards` column

```py
df_ = pd.concat([df_final, df_final['allocation.rewards'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row[0]))], axis=1)
df_ = df_.drop('allocation.rewards', 1)

  MODULE APPLICATION     GUID2     METHOD                timestamp  allocation.duration      GUID           expiryDate rewardSubType
0      a           g  gh-gh-gh  Expensive  2021-01-01 07:00:00.497                    1       NaN  2021-01-01 23:59:59         Boxes
1      a           b       NaN       Free  2021-01-02 07:00:00.497                    2  gh-gh-gh  2021-01-02 23:59:59          Keys
```